# Invalid argument on php file

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, arguments

**I'm getting an error that says:**

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/a2pewpnas01_data01/19/3920219/html/wp-content/plugins/estimated-dispatch-date-woocommerce/includes/plugin-functions.php on line 98"

**The line 98 is this:** `foreach($eddwc_holiday as $eddwc_hday){`

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('eddwc_option')){
    function eddwc_option($key){
        $value = EDDWC()->get_option($key);
        return $value;
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_update_variable')){
    function eddwc_update_variable($post_id,$value){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_variable', wc_clean($value) );
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_update_simple')){
    function eddwc_update_simple($post_id,$value){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_simple', wc_clean($value) );
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_update_variation')){
    function eddwc_update_variation($post_id,$value){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_variation', wc_clean($value) );
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_variation')){
    function eddwc_get_variation($post_id){
        return get_post_meta($post_id,EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_variation',true);
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_variable')){
    function eddwc_get_variable($post_id){
        return get_post_meta($post_id,EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_variable',true);
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_simple')){
    function eddwc_get_simple($post_id){
        return get_post_meta($post_id,EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_simple',true);
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_external')){
    function eddwc_get_external($post_id){
        return get_post_meta($post_id,EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_external',true);
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_grouped')){
    function eddwc_get_grouped($post_id){
        return get_post_meta($post_id,EDDWCP_METAKEY.'_grouped',true);
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_actual_date')){
    function eddwc_get_actual_date($value){
        $date = eddwc_get_dispatch_date($value);
        return $date;
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_general_date')){
    function eddwc_get_general_date($value,$seperator = ' - '){
        $general_option = eddwc_option('product_general_date_settings');
        $val = explode(',', $value);
        $final_date = '';
        if(isset($val[0]) && !isset($val[1])){
            $final_date = $val[0];
        } else if(isset($val[0]) && isset($val[1])){
            if($val[0] == $val[1]){
                $final_date = $val[0];
            } else {
                if(isset($general_option['actual_date'])){
                    $final_date = eddwc_get_dispatch_date($val[0]) .$seperator. eddwc_get_dispatch_date($val[1]);
                } else {
                    $final_date = $val[0] .$seperator. $val[1];
                }
            }
        }

        return $final_date;
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_static_date')){
    function eddwc_get_static_date($date = ''){
        $eddwc_range = explode(',' , $date);
        if(count($eddwc_range) > 1){
            if(isset($eddwc_range[0]) && isset($eddwc_range[1]) &&  ($eddwc_range[0] > $eddwc_range[1]) ){ 
                $eddwc_range = $eddwc_range[0]; 
            } else { 
                $eddwc_range = $eddwc_range[1]; 
            }           
        } else {
            if(isset($eddwc_range[0])){
                $eddwc_range = $eddwc_range[0]; 
            }
        }

        return $eddwc_range;
    }
}
if(!function_exists('eddwc_get_dispatch_date')){
    function eddwc_get_dispatch_date($date) { 
        $eddwc_holiday = eddwc_option('holiday');
        $eddwc_holidays = array();
        foreach($eddwc_holiday as $eddwc_hday){
            $eddwc_holidays[] = $eddwc_hday['date'];
        }

        $eddwc_workdays = eddwc_option('operation_days');
        $cutOff = eddwc_option('day_cutoftime');
        list($cut_hrs,$cut_min) = explode(':',$cutOff);
        $cut_hrs = intval($cut_hrs);
        $cut_min = intval($cut_min);

        $wp_timezone_string = get_option('timezone_string');
        $wp_timezone_offset = get_option('gmt_offset');

        if ($wp_timezone_string) {
            $eddwc_timezone = $wp_timezone_string;
        } else {
            $eddwc_timezone = ini_get('date.timezone');
        }
        date_default_timezone_set($eddwc_timezone);

        $eddwc_date = new DateTime;
        $eddwc_cut_off = $cutOff;
        $eddwc_time = clone $eddwc_date;
        $eddwc_time->setTime($cut_hrs,$cut_min);

        $eddwc_next_date = clone $eddwc_date;

        if ($eddwc_date >= $eddwc_time){
            $eddwc_next_date->modify('+1 day');             
        }

        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $date){
            $eddwc_next_date->modify('+1 day');
            $ndate = strtolower($eddwc_next_date->format('D'));
            if (in_array($ndate, $eddwc_workdays)) {
                //$i++;
                if (in_array($eddwc_next_date->format('d-m-Y'), $eddwc_holidays) == false) {
                    $i++;
                }
            }

        }
        return $eddwc_next_date->format(eddwc_option('date_display_format'));
    }
}
?>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: $eddwc_holiday is more than likely not an array. `var_dump($eddwc_holiday);` before that line to verify.

Comment: This  `$eddwc_holiday` argument need to be a defined array or object… and I think is certainly not the case… That's the only possible explanation.

Comment: Exactly as the above comments have stated. Only run the `foreach()` IF the variable is an array.